# Cloud Function cannot import name 'storage' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

```
2021-12-23T17:33:55.099Zpython-api-request cannot import name 'storage' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
cannot import name 'storage' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

Why am I getting this error? This is my requirements.txt

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
pandas
requests
datetime
google-cloud
```

And my main.py

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
from google.cloud import storage
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```

It works completely fine in my local machine terminal when I execute my code but why is Cloud Function complaining about my user code?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? An update would've been nice.

Answer (score 6):

Your requirements.txt should have `google-cloud-storage` rather than just `google-cloud`. The base doesn't contain the storage package, they are each separately installed but then called from the base package.

Comment: Correct. Also, the **google-cloud** package is deprecated and should not be used. https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me is this:

1
If the package is already installed, you can try upgrading it to the latest version:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

2
If the issue still persists, you can also try uninstalling and then reinstalling the package:

```
pip uninstall google-cloud-storage

pip install google-cloud-storage
```

3
After you have installed or upgraded the package, you can try importing storage from google.cloud again.